# extract plots from list R

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, gridextra

I have made a function:

```
mtcars_plot_fun <- function(cyl_in, gear_in) {
  car_data <- mtcars %>%
    filter(cyl == cyl_in,
           gear == gear_in)
  p <- car_data %>% ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = qsec, fill = gear)) +
    geom_point() 
  print(p)
}
```

Then a loop that makes plots and stores them in the list object `gg_obj`

```
cyls <- c(4, 6)

gears <- c(3, 4)

for (cyl in cyls) {
  for (gear in gears) {
    gg_obj <- mtcars_plot_fun(cyl_in = cyl, gear_in = gear)
    }
}
```

Now I want to extract the plots I need from `gg_obj` and use `grid.arrange()`, `gridExtra` or similar to plot them.
How can I pull out the plots I want, and store them as unique objects to plot in a grid?

Comment: Provided `gg_obj` has multiple ggplots, then `gg_obj[[1]]` should give you the first plot.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: question updated with decent reprex, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do.call` to use your list of plots as arguments for `grid.arrange`.

For example:

```
do.call(grid.arrange, list.of.plots, ncol=2)
```